# In systemC how do you get the sc_time in the end_of_simulation routine

Tags: systemc

I would like to report what the time is at the end of a simulation.  I thought that I would use the end_of_simulation routine, and just do a sc_timestamp in the routine to do this.

The problem is that the kernel has terminated before end_of_simulation, and I get a bogus timestamp.

I can't really use a thread to determine this because what pulls me out of the simulation is that all of the threads are waiting on events.  There is no "master thread" that I could just store the timestamp.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a little hackish but you could update a global time variable with sc_time_stamp() at key points in your code that might be the end of a sim, like before waits or before you return from a time consuming function? Then after returning from sc_start() you would have the   last time value from the code you care about.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
cout << "Start of simulation is " << sc_time_stamp() << endl;
sc_start (); // sc_start (-1);
cout << "End of simulation is " << sc_time_stamp() << endl;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.

For the simulation to run is necessary to stipulate the time that it must take in total.
sc_start(total_time, SC_NS).

total_time is the final time of simulation.

Comment: He is starting his sim with sc_start() or sc_start(-1) which tells the simulator to run until there are no more events to service rather than running for a specific length of time. When you use this method the time is advanced to a very large number to make sure no more events need to be serviced. It talks a little bit about it here: http://www.scribd.com/doc/53124102/27/sc-start